# How to solve "redirected you too many times" error?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, admin

AdminLoginController

```php
public function authenticate(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
    [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
       
    if($validator->passes()) {
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],
             $request->get('remember'))) {
            Log::info('login success');
            $admin =Auth::guard('admin')->user();
            
            if($admin->role == 2) {
                return redirect()->route('admin/dashboard');
            }
            else if($admin->role == 1) {
                $admin =Auth::guard('admin')->user();
            }
            return redirect()->route('/department');
        }
    }
}
```

Middleware

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    } 
    else {
        return redirect("admin/login");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times
```

[image: Screenshot of the error web page]